How to migrate Oracle's CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF, CONNECT_BY_ROOT, and CONNECT BY PRIOR to SQL Server?
I have the following query that I am trying to translate:
SELECT
    sub.COLUMN_1,
    sub.COLUMN_2,
    sub.COLUMN_3,
    CONNECT_BY_ROOT sub.COLUMN_4,
    CONNECT_BY_ROOT sub.COLUMN_5,
    CONNECT_BY_ROOT sub.COLUMN_6,
    CONNECT_BY_ROOT sub.COLUMN_7,
    CONNECT_BY_ROOT sub.COLUMN_8,
    CONNECT_BY_ROOT sub.COLUMN_9,
    sub.COLUMN_10
FROM
    TABLE sub
WHERE
    1 = CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF
AND
    (
        2 <= LEVEL
    OR
        sub.COLUMN_11 IS NULL
    )
START WITH
    0 = sub.COLUMN_12
CONNECT BY PRIOR
    sub.COLUMN_8 = sub.COLUMN_13
AND
    sub.COLUMN_7 = PRIOR sub.COLUMN_7

I have come as far as to understand that CONNECT BY indicates a hierarchical query, in its simplest form expressed by a parent CTE with an anchor union-ing a child joining to its parent in a recursive manner.
This is where I am currently stuck:
    1 = CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF
AND
    (
        2 <= LEVEL
    OR
        sub.COLUMN_11 IS NULL
    )


How do I define the ORDER BY clause needed for the CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF?

How to approach the AND conditions?



Rather than asking someone to translate your query, provide us with a [mre] with sample data and desired results. That way not only do you not need an expert in both SQL Server & Oracle, but you/we can actually verify that the solution is correct.

The problem is that I don't know how much of the complexity I can remove based on my lack of understanding how e.g. multiple arguments in the CONNECT BY clause and the CONNECT_BY_LEAF work. I will work on some sample data, thanks for the pointers

I'm not suggesting you remove complexity... just provide the requirements in a form other than an Oracle query...

It's wrong to assume contributors with sqlserver knowledge also have oracle expertise..

not only the question has been asked many times here but good tutorials exist and easy to find, like https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/recursive-subquery-factoring-11gr2

I haven't come across a question that covered quite this complexity. Your link was very helpful, I edited my question to explain where I am currently stuck
